# Upgrading Fedora 10 to 11 on Slicehost

Tags: linux, fedora, slicehost

I have used the following instructions:

```
# yum -y update
# yum install preupgrade
# preupgrade-cli
# reboot
```

It could not upgrade grub and after a reboot its still Fedora 10. The problem seems to be slicehost specific. Can you help me?

Comment: Belongs to superuser.com.

Comment: The FAQ starts with "Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity."

Comment: doesn't belong on superuser- slicehost is a virtual server host (part of rackspace).

Comment: Sorry, didn't recognized that this is a server system. (Isn't it quite unusual to run a server on Fedora?)

Answer (score 3):

The steps are a little tricky to get from Fedora 10 to Fedora 11 on a Xen VPS.  You might want to [try this method instead](http://rackerhacker.com/2009/06/11/upgrading-from-fedora-10-cambridge-to-fedora-11-leonidas/).

Answer (score 2):

Have you switched to the Fedora 11 Repos? What exactly have you done?

Have you followed [these](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/YumUpgradeFaq) instructions?

Comment: http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=3775 It seems to be that slicehost assigns the kernel at startup, I can't alter Grub settings. The only easy way to migrate to F11 is to load their vanilla F11 image and rebuilding the system.